# why my angular component looks like 0x0 on my browser?

Tags: angular, typescript

Im actually learning angular and Im triying to create a new componet, but when I tried on my browser it dosen't shows up

```
`<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ProyectTest</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-test-component></app-test-component>
</body>
</html>`





@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-component',
  templateUrl: './test-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-component.component.css']
})
export class TestComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

[here you can see how it looks like on live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddn7l.png)

Comment: your `test-componet` should be a child of `app-root`, `app-root` is the main container in your Angular project. from there, you start adding more component trees. unless you want to have 2 ROOT components...

Comment: You need to attach `app-test-component` inside the `app.component.html` template

Answer (score 0):

### Why don't you see `app-test-component` in index.html?

I would like to answer this in bullets

- `app.module.ts` has `bootstrap` options, where the root of the component is defined `bootstrap: [AppComponent]`
- When Angular application kicks in, it only looks up for the `bootstrap` array, and instantiates that component as the root component. Others will be ignored.

  ```
  @NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [...],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent], // <------- single component bootstrap
  })
  export class AppModule { }
  ```

### How to make it work?

- Amend bootstrap array with the component that you want to create as component root.

  ```
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, TestComponentComponent],
  ```
- This way you can tell angular to `bootstrap` or have two `root` components.

> **Important Note:-** In general it is recommended to keep a single `bootstrap` component (as it comes with the initial CLI project) unless you have usecase to do it. For learning purpose you can use this.

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ab7xww)